# Using JQueryUI dialog in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i'm trying to replace the standard javascript confirm function with a JQueryUI dialog.  I've searched for solutions, but nothing seems to work for me.  What i want is simple:  click an ASP.Net button, display the dialog, continue if "Yes" is pressed.  Current javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            bgiframe: true,
            open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide() },
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return true;
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function showDialog() {
        $("#confirmDialog").dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
```

ASP.NET code:

```
            <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" CssClass='button' onmouseout="this.className='button'"
                onmouseover="this.className='button:hover'" runat='server' Text='Delete' Width='1in'
                Height="30px" OnClientClick="javascript:showDialog();" OnClick="DeleteSetup"/>
```

What's happening is that the dialog is displayed, but DeleteSetup vb.net sub is called before anything is selected in the dialog.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: jQuery dialog doesn't block a javascript execution. So everytime showDialog function will return false value and server side event wasn't fired.

Comment: Put the DeleteSetup inside "Yes" function callback.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your `OnClientClick` declaration to this

`OnClientClick="return showDialog();"`

Comment: I changed the OnClientClick as recommended, but that didn't help.  The dialog appears, but processing continues, the OnClick event fires (even though the dialog was declared modal). I'm sure the reason this i can't make this work is my lack of understanding (though i've tried).  All i want is for this dialog to behave like the standard javascript confirm function.  How?  Thanks.